# React functional component - State is changed, component is re-rendered but DOM is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, virtual-dom

I'm facing a weird issue with react functional components.

### Context

I have a parent component with two state objects. On useEffect hook, I'm making an API call and setting the state with received response data, and then I'm processing this raw data with some attributes and setting this in the second state.

And on click event of an input element, I'm again processing the raw data(with another set of attributes) which I saved in the first state and then setting this processed data to the second state object.

So everything is working as expected. State object is updating in the initial rendering and on click event also this state is being updated and component re-renders

But the problem is with the DOM, the DOM is not reflecting this state change. I'm wondering what could be the reason. I'm adding some pseudocode to emulate the same scenario.

```
function ParentComponent = () => {
  const [rawData, setRawData] = useSate({});
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const handleClick = ({attr: 'new attr'}) => {
    const getProcessedData = processData(rawData, { attr });
    setData(getProcessedData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('apiurl');
      setRawData(res);
      const getProcessedData = processData(res, { attr:'process based on this attr'});
      setData(getProcessedData);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  return (<Container>
    <button onClick={() => handleClick({attr: 'new attr'})}>Click me</button>
    //Here the child component recieves the updated data on click event but its not reflecting the DOM.
    <Child data={data} /> 
  </Container>);
}
```

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be interested in what `processData` looks like. My instinct is it's mutating the input object rather than creating a copy

Comment: @Nick, processData is doing some object manipulation and returning that modified object. Are you suggesting creating a copy of `res` in two cases, And pass to the processData function?  But I'm curious how the object mutation will cause the react to not update the DOM.

Comment: Yeah, I’m suggesting copying the object inside the process function. React’s diffing algorithm relies on referential equality. If there’s no object reference change, it won’t update the DOM.

Comment: I tried it with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) inside the process function and did the manipulation on that cloned object. But doesn't really seem to be working :(

Comment: Ah, that’s too bad. As-is, the code you’ve provided doesn’t really give people here a minimal reproducible example to help troubleshoot. It’d be great if you could post more of your code, especially the process function and the render logic of the child component, showing what you expect and what’s happening.

Comment: @Nick The issue was with the Child component, I was doing an iteration of the data which it received and the key(the react key) that I have given wasn't unique. when I have given a unique key, it started working. Thanks for your help :)